# My text has large vertical spaces between each new line within a div?

Tags: html, css, text, spacing

If you run the following code you will notice that the word *hello* is output vertically in a white div with a large distance between each new line. I've tried many different things such as getting rid of the margin style (not sure if it mattered) but no luck finding a solution.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">  
<title>div_experiment</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type = "text/css">
body
{
    background-color: black;
}
#div_id
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overfill: auto auto;    
    max-height: 696px;  
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
</script>   
<div id = "div_id">
    <p>hello</p><br>
    <p>hello</p><br>
    <p>hello</p><br>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `p` tags have default `margin` at top and bottom. and also no need of using `br` while using `display: block` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paragraph elements have that margin, not the container. So this rule should fix it:

```
#div_id p {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: It reduces it I guess. Any way to make it even smaller?

Comment: It's completely gone. The breaks you see now are from `<br>` elements. Remove them if you want the space removed and use the paragraph margin/padding to control the spacing more accurately.

Comment: Was just about to paste my own. :)